# Could not normalize image parameters for file.png - MediaWiki

Tags: elasticsearch, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor, mediawiki-visualeditor

I'm using:

MediaWiki 1.37.1
PHP 7.4.3 (fpm-fcgi)
Elasticsearch 5.6.16
VisualEditor 0.1.2

When I go to a page and click on Edit > Insert > Images and media; And when I start searching for files it works great, unless there's a PDF file, then the query returns an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlIW0.png).
This only happens with PDF files.

I searched everywhere for this code error and I couldn't find a solution.

This is the request url:

/api.php?action=query&format=json&generator=allimages&gaisort=timestamp&gaidir=descending&iiurlheight=200&iiprop=dimensions%7Curl%7Cmediatype%7Cextmetadata%7Ctimestamp%7Cuser&prop=imageinfo&gaiuser=Admin&iiurlwidth=300&gailimit=15

I noticed when I remove the 'prop=imageinfo' from the query, it works with no problems.

Any ideas, suggestions and solutions are very appreciated.

Comment: Have you got MW extension PDFHandler and xpdf-utils installed?

Comment: Yes, they are both installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed PdfHandler and it worked fine.